# Как вернуть JsonObject через getParams в Volley, Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

Хочу отправить json на сервер в таком формате:

```
{"name":"apiName","param":{}}
```

Я использую библиотеку Volley и переопределяю метод getParams таким образом:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
{
}
```

В этом методе создаю два json objects:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();

try
{
 jsonObject.put("name", "apiName");
 jsonObject.put("param", jsonObject2);
}
 catch (JSONException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Каким образом я могу отправить объект с использованием или без использования getParams?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил так:

```
final String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
   try { return jsonString == null ? null : jsonString.getBytes("utf-8"); }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать [таким способом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344448/how-to-send-json-object-to-server-using-volley-in-android):

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();


            Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("un", "xyz@gmail.com");
            postParam.put("p", "somepasswordhere");


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.URL_LOGIN, new JSONObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }



    };

    jsonObjReq.setTag(TAG);
    // Adding request to request queue
    queue.add(jsonObjReq);

    // Cancelling request
    /* if (queue!= null) {
    queue.cancelAll(TAG);
    } */

}
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540464/volley-post-request-send-json-object-in-json-array-request?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636853/http-post-request-send-jsonobject-with-volley), [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8MWUYpwoTQ) и [статья](https://medium.com/techpin/https-medium-com-s2purno-volley-get-and-post-jsonobject-request-46fb8a46f799)

Comment: Спасибо! Должно подойти.